# Prove that these conditions are equivalent

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

$X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables taking non-negative value.

Suppose $Z=X+Y$ and $P(Z=n)\gt0\quad(n=0,1,2…)$

I need to prove two conditions below are  equivalent:

(1)
There are $\lambda_a\gt0, \lambda\gt0$

$$P(X=x)=\frac{e^{-\lambda_a}\lambda^x_a}{x!}, \enspace P(Y=y)=\frac{e^{-\lambda_b}\lambda^y_b}{y!},\quad x,y=0,1,2,…$$

(2)
There is $p(0\lt p\lt 1)$ and $n$ is a non-negative value.

$$P(X=x\mid Z=n)=\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    n \\
    x \\
  \end{array}
\right)p^x(1-p)^{n-x}, \quad x=0,1,…n$$

I have tried to prove for (2)->(1), I did not make it as I did not have PDF of $Z$